# How do I check how much weapons have been strengthened by Material Grind?

Tags: holocure-save-the-fans

Kaela Kovalskia's Material Grind skill states:

> Targets have a x% chance to drop an Ore Deposit, which may be destroyed with Hammer Swing to drop Ore. Gaining 10 of a type of Ore will strengthen all weapons by 1, 2 or 3%.

Is there a way to check how much my weapons have been strengthened by Material Grind? Or alternatively, is there a way to check the total amount of ore I've collected so I can calculate the strength bonus myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentage increase to weapon damage from Material Grind is shown with a sword and gem icon in the bottom left corner of the screen.

[image: Percent buff sign]